# points between 2 locations in google map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw grid lines in google maps. On research I got a code for drawing polylines in google maps. But it requires cordinates of the points on which lines are to be drawn. Is there any alternate way to draw polylines between points without knowing the cordinates? Or is there any way to know the cordinates of the points in 1 km distance between 2 points? I know the cordinates of the points between which grid lines are to be drawn.

Comment: Take a look at [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#spherical)

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/25079/ . Go through this link, download the javascript code. Then call to addruler() method from your code. It will work.

Comment: I know this is very old question but couldn't find answer anywhere. Do you know how to achieve this?